# Jquery fs scroller in ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using Jquery fs scroller in my website . The problem is that I need to add scrollbar via fs scroller by ajax call in some pages but the js library is not loading in ajax success . Can anybody tell me how to do this ? Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

If plugin is already loaded before ajax, you should be able to just call it on ajax complete.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $(".scrollbar").scroller();
});
```